# Excel pivot table "Distinct Count" not compatible with Group for dates?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Using Excel 2013, I need a pivot table which:

- Counts unique values in a field ('Distinct Count')
- Groups the data by Year and Quarter

If I create the pivot table by checking "Add this data to the Data Model" then the "Distinct Count" option is available as expected. However, I cannot group my date columns (both Group and Ungroup are grayed out), making the report unusable.

OTOH if I don't check "Add this data to the Data Model" when I create the pivot table, Grouping dates works fine but I lose the "Distinct Count" option as expected. Exact same data with date column formatted as short date.

Can someone verify and/or enlighten me about the reason?

Comment: Add a column to your original dataset that performs the grouping. As an example, on a row with a date of 3/14/2018 you can add a field (column) to display "Oct-2018" (or even store the data as a `Date` value of 3/1/2018). You can extend this to add a Quarter column as well. Then you'll have those fields available in your pivot table without the grouping and you should then have access to your "Distinct Count" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct: the grouping feature is not available in Pivots based on the Data Model, and the Distinct Count feature is not available on 'traditional' pivots. But you can either use formulas on your source data to add the groups there, and pivot that field, or use DAX formulas to create groups within the Data Model.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I know there are workarounds but was surprised that these functions were incompatible.

Comment: You know I have to say this is pretty big product miss. Before this I didn't think of pivot tables as coming in two flavors with non-overlapping features. Distinct count of items grouped by date seems like a pretty significant use case...

Comment: I agree. Possibly grouping via the UI would introduce significant inefficiency vs doing it via DAX, and MS made the call to leave it out given an OLAP PivotTable may have many millions of rows. Usually it's fairly easy to add a new table into your datamodel with the groups required, and then set up a relationship in your model, and simply use that new table field instead of what you were using before.